# no value given for one or more parameters visual studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i checked my spellings they are okay
here is my "update"code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox3.Text = TextBox6.Text - TextBox2.Text
    pro = "provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\chemz high school fees management system\chemz_db.accdb "
    connstring = pro
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
    myconnection.Open()
    command = "update SCHOOL_FEES set [Fees]='" & TextBox6.Text & "',[Fees_paid]='" & TextBox2.Text & "',[Fees_owed]='" & TextBox3.Text & "',[Practical_fee]='" & TextBox4.Text & "',[Sports_fee]='" & TextBox5.Text & "'where[Learner_ID]=" & TextBox1.Text & ""
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
    MsgBox("UPDATED")
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myconnection.Close()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        MsgBox("UPDATE FAILED")

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: First things first, you should learn how to use parameters in your ADO.NET code. Using string concatenation in the way you are can lead to a number of different problems. You are probably seeing one of them here.

Comment: Ignoring that, the issue is with your SQL code and yet you haven't shown us your SQL code, which makes me doubt that you have even looked at it yourself. The VB code that constructs the SQL code may be perfectly fine but it relies on data available only at run time so the resulting SQL may vary. You need to look at the actual result when you run the code. If you had looked at the value of `command` then the issue may been obvious to you and you wouldn't need to ask a question at all. If you ask it though, you need to provide all the relevant information, including the SQL code generated.

Comment: By the way, should you not be waiting until after the SQL has been successfully executed to display the "UPDATED" message? Also, what's the point of that `pro` variable? Why would you not just use `connstring`? That said, why use `connstring` either? Why do you need to set a hard-coded connection string every time you use a connection? Why can't you just set the connection string once, when you create the connection object?

Comment: I suggest that you use an [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to build the connection string so that you do not have to worry about spaces in the path to the database file.

Comment: `TextBox3.Text = TextBox6.Text - TextBox2.Text` How can you subtract on string from another string???

Comment: What does `no value given for one or more parameters visual studio 2013` mean/where does it come from, and what is your question? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I have showed you how to use parameters. In Access (OleDb) the order that the parameters appear in the command text must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection.

Using...End Using blocks will assure that connection and command are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim Command = "update SCHOOL_FEES set [Fees]= @Fee, [Fees_paid]= @FeePaid, [Fees_owed]= @FeeOwed, [Practical_fee]= @PracticalFee, [Sports_fee]= @SportsFee where [Learner_ID]= @ID;"

    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\chemz high school fees management system\chemz_db.accdb "),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(Command, myconnection)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Fee", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox6.Text)
            .Add("@FeePaid", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox2.Text)
            .Add("@FeeOwed", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox3.Text)
            .Add("@PracticalFee", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
            .Add("@SportsFee", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox5.Text)
            .Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        End With
        Try
            myconnection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("UPDATED")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("UPDATE FAILED")
        End Try
    End Using
    ClearTextBoxes()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearTextBoxes()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't normally do it, but there were a couple of typos in the code which I corrected rather than pointing out.